# Prove or disprove there always exists a set of four numbers of which product is a perfect square out of arbitrarily chosen $48$ positive integers ...

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> Question: Assume you choose a set of arbitrary $48$ positive integers so that the number of distinct prime factors of all those numbers is $10$. Prove or disprove there always exists a set of four numbers out of the $48$ positive integers of which product is a perfect square.

I think that it uses pigeon hole, but I couldn't make a progress.